# How to set OnTouchListener for toolbar popup (overflow) menu

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-5.0-lollipop

If it's an image button (`app:showAsAction="always"`), I can do this:

```
findViewById(R.id.action_settings).setOnTouchListener(listener)
```

But if it's in overflow menu (`app:showAsAction="never"`), `findViewById` will return `null`. What's the easiest and most portable solution to this? (instead of A LOT OF reflection)

P.S. I want to get touch location that's passed in `MotionEvent` in `OnTouchListener`, so I definitely DON'T want to know how to use `onOptionItemsSelected` or `OnClickListener`, etc.

Comment: get view of menu, call findViewById from that view. I do not any other way

Comment: how did you put imageView inside overflow menu o.O ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In My demo app I was able to make the touch event fire using the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    boolean result = false;
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        //Returning false here allows the touch event to bubble up.
        result = false;
    } else {
        result = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean dispatchGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.d(TAG, "dispatchGenericMotionEvent");
    // do some other stuff
    return super.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(ev);
}
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.d(TAG, "dispatchTouchEvent");
    // do stuff here....
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: I want to set `OnTouchListener`, not `OnClickListener`. To be more specific, I want to get the touch location in `MotionEvent` passed with that. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you updated the answer. And yeah, `dispatchTouchEvent` worked quite well for me. Thanks! :-D